# VBA Excel Scraping

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am getting started with trying to learn about scraping. I got this page that is behind a login and I remember reading that you should not try to do the (1), (2) or (3) thing after get element by tagname. But that you should rather get something more unique like a Classname or ID. But can someone please tell me why

This the GetTag **works** and

```
Dim Companyname As String
Companyname = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innertext
```

This GetClass **do not work**

```
Dim Companyname As String
Companyname = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("account-website-name").innertext
```

This is the text that I am scraping

```
<span class="account-website-name" data-journey-name="true">Dwellington Journey</span>
```

Comment: Whenever you use something that can potentially get more that a single element you need to provide an ordinal index. You do this in the first example with the **(1)** which references the second `<span>` element (ordinals are zero based). In your second example you omit the ordinal so `.getElementsByClassName` doesn't know which to return, even if there is only one that matches.

Comment: You are a boss man! Thanks!

Comment: @Jeeped That sounds more like an answer than a comment, how about fleshing it out, posting it as one and getting the rep you seem to deserve?

Comment: Thanks @Aiken - I had just gone to meta to read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments) and try to decide on a course of action. It seems that re-submitting as an Answer Community Wiki is the preferred treatment.

Comment: @Jeeped I don't see why it has to be a community wiki, you posted the comment which turned out to be an answer, why lose out on your rep? Posting as a community wiki is when someone else answered in the comments but hasn't posted an actual answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get**ELEMENT**byProperty vs get**ELEMENTS**byProperty

There are primarily two distinct types of commands to retrieve one or more elements from a web page's `.Document`; those that return a single object and those that return a collection of objects.

**Getting an ELEMENT**

When `getElementById` is used, you are asking for a single object (e.g. `MSHTML.IHTMLElement`). In this case the properties (e.g. `.Value`, `.innerText`, `.outerHtml`, etc) can be retrieved directly. There isn't supposed to be more than a single unique id property within an HTML body so this function should safely return the only element within the `i.e.document` that matches.

```
'typical VBA use of getElementById
Dim CompanyName As String
CompanyName = ie.document.getElementById("CompanyID").innerText
```

Caveat: I've noticed a growing number of web designers who seem to think that using the same `id` for multiple elements is oh-key-doh-key as long as the id's are within different parent elements like different `<div>` elements. AFAIK, this is patently wrong but seems to be a growing practise. Be careful on what is returned when using `.getElementById`.

**Getting ELEMENTS**

When using `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName`, etc. where the word *Elements* is plural, you are returning a *collection* (e.g. `MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection`) of objects, even if that collection contains only one or even none. If you want to use these to directly access an property of one of the elements within the collection, an *ordinal index* number must be supplied so that a single element within the collection is referenced. The index number within these collections is zero based (i.e. the first starts at *(0)*).

```
'retrieve the text from the third <span> element on a webpage
Dim CompanyName As String
CompanyName = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")(2).innerText

'output all <span> classnames to the Immediate window until the right one comes along
'retrieve the text from the first <span> element with a classname of 'account-website-name'
Dim e as long, es as long
es = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span").Length - 1
For e = 0 To es
    Debug.Print ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")(e).className
    If ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")(e).className = "account-website-name" Then
        CompanyName = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")(e).innerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next e

'same thing, different method
Dim eSPN as MSHTML.IHTMLElement, ecSPNs as MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
ecSPNs = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
For Each eSPN in ecSPNs
    Debug.Print eSPN.className
    If eSPN.className = "account-website-name" Then
        CompanyName = eSPN.innerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next eSPN 
Set eSPN = Nothing: Set ecSPNs = Nothing
```

To summarize, if your `Internet.Explorer` method uses *Elements* (plural) rather than *Element* (singular), you are returning a collection which must have an index number appended if you wish to treat one of the elements within the collection as a single element.

Comment: And... that was just impressive. Thanks man! And I agree, it feels like the same ID thing is spreading like a wild fire. After this I actually got 4 different number with both same ID and classname but under different parents. Got all that figures out. But thank you again. A single S makes a lot of difference.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS selector:**

You can achieve the same thing with a CSS selector of `.account-website-name`

The **"."** means className. This will return a collection of matching elements if there are more than one.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

You apply the selector with the `.querySelectorAll` method of `.document`. This returns a `nodeList` which you traverse the `.Length` of, accessing items by index, starting from 0.

```
Dim aNodeList As Object, i As Long
Set aNodeList = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".account-website-name")

For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length -1
    Debug.Print aNodeList.Item(i).innerText
    ' Debug.Print aNodeList(i).innerText ''<== sometimes this syntax instead
Next
```